# Find the number occurences of each word in a document?

Tags: algorithm

I was asked the question in an interview. The interviewer told me to assume that there exists a function say getNextWord() to return the next word in a given document. My task was to design a data structure to implement the task, and give an algorithm that constructs a list of all words with their frequencies.

Being from a C++ background, my answer was to create a `multimap` of `string` and then insert all words in it, and later display the `count` of it. I was however told later, to do this in a more *generic* way. By generic he meant that he didn't want me to use a library feature. Also I guess a multimap is implemented internally as a 2-3 tree or so, so for the multimap solution to be generic I would need to code the 2-3 tree as well.

Although tries did come to mind, implementing one during an interview was out of question for me. So, I just wanted to know if there are better ways of achieving it? Or is there a way to implement it in a smooth manner using tries?

Comment: Can you please expand on *generic*?

Comment: By generic he meant to say, that he didn't want me to use a library feature. Also I guess a multimap is implemented internally as a 2-3 tree or so..by generic he wanted me to code the 2-3 tree..

Comment: I would guess he wanted you to describe the data structure you are using, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table or he might want you to make a pseudo-code rather than C++ implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any [**histogram**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) based algorithm would be both effient and generic in here. The idea is simple: build a histogram from the data. **A generic interface for a histogram is a `Map<String,Integer>`**

Iterate the document once (with your nextDoc() method), while maintaining your histogram.

The best implementation for this interface, in terms of big O notations - would probably be to **use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)**, and in each leaf node - add the counter of occurances.

Getting the actual `(word,number)` pairs from the trie will be done by a simple DFS on the trie.

This solution gives you `O(n * |S|)` time complexity, where |S| is the average size for a string.

**The insertion algorithm for each word:**

Each time you add a new word: check if it already exists, if it does - increase the counter, else - add the word to the dictionary with a counter value of 1.

Comment: IF C++ - Shouldn't it be Multimap<String,Integer> to allow repeated keys?

Comment: @goldenmean: You do not want repeated keys - you count them on your own, I think that's what the interviewer meant by "more generic"

Answer (score 2):

I'd try to implement a [B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) (or smth quite similar) to store all the words. Therefore I could easily find a next word, if already have it and increase associated counter in the node. Or just insert a new one.

The time complexity in that case would be: `O(nlogn)`, where `n` is all words count and `logn` is a Big-Oh for such kind of tree.

Comment: This seens not to be more generic than using a multimap

Comment: And also is unnecessary slow by O(log n) factor. Hashmap or trie are better and faster.

Comment: May be generic in this context means smth other then a standart data structure implementation? Because we have naturally map, hash and others in C++: std, C#:Generic. I believe, the interviewer just wanted from the candidate to hear not about well-known algo implementation but about classic approaches (trees, for example).

Comment: @usamec. Hashmap has `O(1 + n/k)` case for search. Yes, you can use any kind of HashTable too for this purpose. I don't mind :)

Comment: Note that each compare OP of two strings is `O(|S|)` - where `|S|` is the average size of a string. Thus, the algorithm is `O(|S| * nlogn)`, and not `O(nlogn)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be a a [Trie](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=usingTries). O(N) is given in this case (both for insertion and getting the count). Just store the count in an additional space at every node.

Basically each node in the tree contains 26 links to 26 possible children (1 for each letter) + 1 counter (for words the are terminated in the current node)
.
Just look at the link for a graphic image of a trie.